# how to draw ellipses without scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ellipse

I am trying to represent niche of species by drawing inertia ellipses. The function to do this in `ade4` is `niche`. Here is an example:

```
data(trichometeo)
pca1 <- dudi.pca(trichometeo$meteo, scan = FALSE)
nic1 <- niche(pca1, log(trichometeo$fau + 1), scan = FALSE)
s.distri(dfxy = nic1$ls, dfdistri = eval.parent(as.list(nic1$call)[[3]]))
```

This graph is not really clear. 
PCA is done on environmental variables.
Each point of the PCA is a study site. In each study site, several species have been observed. The ellipses are the niches of each species.

When building the ellipse of one species, a weight is given to each of the study sites (the points) according to the relative abundance of the species. The center of gravity of these weighed points is the center of the ellipsoid. The width of the ellipse is linked to the variance of the weighed points.

so there is no scatterplot with a factor i could use to use `stat_ellipse`.

Any suggestions on how to do that in `ggplot` graphics ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, finally i found how to plot ellipses in `ggplot`.It is explained in the first part of the answer. The second part describes how to extract ellipsoid coordinates from niche analysis in ade4.

**Draw a simple ellipsoid in ggplot** In order to do that, you have to build a data frame with to columns x and y for coordinates of some of the points that compose the ellipse, and use `geom_polygon` as follow:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(x = c(-0.74970124137657, -0.776450364352299,     -0.804256933708176, 
-0.833011209618567, -0.862599712093033, -0.892905668830007, -0.923809476063724, 
-0.955189170585639, -0.986920911077492, -1.01887946685642, -1.05093871210323, 
-1.08297212362341, -1.11485328017637, -1.14645636140231, -1.1776566443777, 
-1.20833099583969, -1.23835835813684, -1.26762022698836, -1.29600111916637, 
-1.32338902825544, -1.34967586669074, -1.37475789233028, -1.39853611787775, 
-1.42091670154015, -1.44181131737848, -1.46113750388986, -1.47881898944545, 
-1.49478599329964, -1.50897550098285, -1.52133151299083, -1.53180526578912, 
-1.5403554242604, -1.54694824483541, -1.55155770866329, -1.55416562429619, 
-1.55476169948255, -1.55334358178592, -1.54991686786897, -1.54449508140603, 
-1.53709961971128, -1.52775966929336, -1.51651209066957, -1.50340127289419, 
-1.48847895837522, -1.47180403867071, -1.45344232207069, -1.43346627388192, 
-1.41195473044039, -1.38899258798039, -1.3646704675878, -1.3390843575601, 
-1.31233523458437, -1.28452866522849, -1.2557743893181, -1.22618588684363, 
-1.19587993010666, -1.16497612287294, -1.13359642835103, -1.10186468785917, 
-1.06990613208025, -1.03784688683344, -1.00581347531326, -0.973932318760297, 
-0.94232923753436, -0.911128954558971, -0.880454603096979,    -0.850427240799828, 
-0.821165371948307, -0.792784479770296, -0.765396570681226, -0.739109732245926, 
-0.714027706606386, -0.690249481058919, -0.66786889739652, -0.646974281558191, 
-0.627648095046803, -0.609966609491222, -0.593999605637033, -0.579810097953819, 
-0.567454085945835, -0.556980333147553, -0.548430174676264, -0.541837354101259, 
-0.537227890273375, -0.534619974640476, -0.534023899454122, -0.535442017150752, 
-0.538868731067695, -0.544290517530637, -0.551685979225388, -0.561025929643302, 
-0.572273508267099, -0.585384326042479, -0.600306640561448, -0.616981560265954, 
-0.63534327686597, -0.655319325054748, -0.676830868496273, -0.699793010956271, 
-0.724115131348859), y = c(0.325013216091984, 0.336960163623126, 
0.346538198705152, 0.353709521209382, 0.358445829202159, 0.360728430639646, 
0.360548317136793, 0.357906199519309, 0.352812505018361, 0.345287336119057, 
0.335360391225119, 0.323070847452856, 0.308467206016976, 0.291607100818459, 
0.272557070989873, 0.251392298295821, 0.228196310424862, 0.203060651343884, 
0.176084520015889, 0.147374378907005, 0.117043533827776, 0.085211686766882, 
0.0520044634820859, 0.0175529177127555, -0.0180069860293719, 
-0.0545349090500008, -0.0918866923249894, -0.129914925430158, 
-0.168469528302887, -0.207398343539562, -0.246547736891326, -0.285763203588276, 
-0.324889978099203, -0.363773644920435, -0.402260747983286, -0.440199396275052, 
-0.477439863283444, -0.513835177898732, -0.549241704441568, -0.583519709527388, 
-0.616533913530252, -0.648154024469714, -0.678255252213751, -0.7067188009684, 
-0.733432338110486, -0.758290437513162, -0.781194995614671, -0.802055618588285, 
-0.820789979085438, -0.837324141144163, -0.851592851980555, -0.863539799511696, 
 -0.873117834593722, -0.880289157097953, -0.885025465090729, -0.887308066528217, 
-0.887127953025363, -0.884485835407879, -0.879392140906931, -0.871866972007626, 
-0.861940027113689, -0.849650483341425, -0.835046841905545, -0.818186736707027, 
-0.799136706878442, -0.77797193418439, -0.754775946313431, -0.729640287232453, 
-0.702664155904458, -0.673954014795575, -0.643623169716345, -0.611791322655452, 
-0.578584099370656, -0.544132553601326, -0.508572649859198, -0.47204472683857, 
-0.434692943563581, -0.396664710458413, -0.358110107585684, -0.31918129234901, 
-0.280031898997246, -0.240816432300296, -0.201689657789369, -0.162805990968137, 
-0.124318887905287, -0.0863802396135213, -0.0491397726051291, 
-0.012744457989841, 0.0226620685529939, 0.0569400736388145, 0.0899542776416779, 
0.12157438858114, 0.151675616325177, 0.180139165079826, 0.206852702221912, 
0.231710801624588, 0.254615359726098, 0.275475982699712, 0.294210343196865, 
0.31074450525559)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

then just plot the polygon:

```
  ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=test, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

[image: handmade ellipsoid]

**For this specific issue**: how to extract ellipses coordinates from a niche analysis with `ade4`:
plots from `ade4` can be put in an oject:

```
data(trichometeo)
pca1 <- dudi.pca(trichometeo$meteo, scan = FALSE)
nic1 <- niche(pca1, log(trichometeo$fau + 1), scan = FALSE)
p1<-s.distri(dfxy = nic1$ls, dfdistri = eval.parent(as.list(nic1$call)[[3]]))
```

p1 is an object of class S4, and it is possible to access slots with data using `@` as follow:

```
p1@s.misc$ellipse
```

this command display a list containing, for each species:

- one vector of x coordinates of the ellipse
- one vector of y coordinates
- one vector with coordinates of the axes of the ellipse

To exctract these coordinates, you use `sapply`

```
listx=sapply(p1@s.misc$ellipse, "[", "x")
listy=sapply(p1@s.misc$ellipse, "[", "y")
```

then transform them into a data frame:

```
tabx=do.call(data.frame, listx)
taby=do.call(data.frame, listy)
```

and combine them in one data frame (i use `melt` from `reshape` package to have a long data frame for `ggplot`)

```
tabx.long=melt(tabx)
taby.long=melt(taby)
tab.fin=cbind.data.frame(tabx.long,taby.long)
```

you can then use this dataframe with the method explained above